# How do you start and stop IIS Express from within TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, iis-express

I may very well be doing something odd but I'm not sure.  I'm trying to configure a TeamCity build agent on a windows xp machine that has IIS Express installed on it.  I would like to create a build step that will start IIS Express and then another build step that will stop it.

I can create a command line build step to starts an instance of IIS Express with a command similar to the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:%1\src\Web /port:80 /systray:false
```

This starts the server but then my log says "Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express" and the step waits.  I don't want the build step to wait.  I want the build to go to the next step.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a simple wrapper executable or batch file that takes exactly same arguments as iisexpress.exe and that wrapper can launch iisexpress.exe with given command line args and return immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was wondering if I was missing something built in but I guess not.

Comment: I know this is old, but I've expanded on this answer below with some useful process considerations. Posting this to aid future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is more complicated than writing a simple batch file, as in most cases you will need to wait until IIS express has been started, then execute some functionality, then stop the IIS express process again.

This last stage is important to avoid starting duplicate sites with multiple builds, which will cause errors and misleading results. We also need to manage the processes carefully so that the 'press Q to quit' prompt doesn't block our app from continuing and executing it's core functionality.

Here's some code I wrote for a console app in C# to run Phantom.JS than will do just that, also it should gracefully handle scenarios where we experience errors.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal class Program
{
    private static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        string iisExpressPath = args[0];
        string websitePath = args[1];
        string websitePort = args[2];
        string phantomJSPath = args[3];
        string jsControllerPath = args[4];

        var startIisTask = StartIis(iisExpressPath, websitePath, websitePort);

        Process iisexpress;
        try
        {
            iisexpress = startIisTask.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.Write("An error occurred while starting IIS express");
            return -1;
        }

        if (iisexpress != null)
        {
            var phantomJS = new Process();
            phantomJS.StartInfo.FileName = phantomJSPath;
            phantomJS.StartInfo.Arguments = jsControllerPath;

            phantomJS.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            phantomJS.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            phantomJS.Start();

            Task.Run(
                () =>
                {
                    string str;
                    while ((str = phantomJS.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (str == "Unable to load the address!")
                        {
                            tcs.SetException(new ArgumentException(str));
                            return;
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(str);
                    }

                    tcs.SetResult(true);
                });

            try
            {
                var complete = tcs.Task.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                phantomJS.Kill();
                iisexpress.Kill();
                return -1;
            }

            iisexpress.Kill();
            return 0;
        }

        Console.Write("An error occurred while starting IIS express");
        return -1;
    }

    private static Task<Process> StartIis(string iisExpressPath, string websitePath, string websitePort)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Process>();

        var iisexpress = new Process();
        iisexpress.StartInfo.FileName = iisExpressPath;
        iisexpress.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/path:{0} /port:{1}", websitePath, websitePort);
        iisexpress.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        iisexpress.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        iisexpress.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Implicit capture is ok here as we are capturing an object we need later.
        iisexpress.Exited += IisexpressOnExited(tcs);

        iisexpress.Start();

        Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                string str;
                while ((str = iisexpress.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (str.Contains("IIS Express is running"))
                    {
                        iisexpress.Exited -= IisexpressOnExited(tcs);
                        tcs.SetResult(iisexpress);
                    }
                }
            });

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private static EventHandler IisexpressOnExited(TaskCompletionSource<Process> tcs)
    {
        return (sender, args) => tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    }
}
```

The app will also pipe the output of phantom.js to it's own console so you can use it for running client side unit tests, but can just as easily be adapted for any build step that may require hosting.

If you want more info, see my post about how to run Jasmine unit tests from within TeamCity with IIS express: http://roysvork.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/running-jasmine-tests-hosted-in-iis-express-as-part-of-a-teamcity-build/

Comment: I don't see an issue with the link the author has included here. It's supplemental, all of the information needed is actually in the answer, and it's fully disclaimed. Let's leave it, shall we?